# Recommendation for JDBC SQL client tool

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Can someone recommend a good, open source, standalone developer tool for querying SQL databases using JDBC and exporting the results to a file? I know a lot of database vendors provide their own tools, but I need one that will allow me to plug in my own custom JDBC driver and work against any database. A GUI is preferable, but not required.

Oracle's SQL Developer is disqualified because it seems to work only with a pre-canned set of JDBC drivers. I have also looked at the [list of tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/sql-clients) at Java-Source.net, but I'm hoping someone can help me narrow down the list based on personal experience. And it needs to be standalone so non-developers can use it, too, which disqualifies Eclipse plug-ins. Thanks!

Comment: Nowadays the best option is [DBEAVER](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/). You can add your custom jdbc driver (in my case it was _polyhedra_) via Database->Driver manager.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) and I'm pretty happy with it. I'm pasting the "Overview" below:

> SQuirreL SQL Client is a graphical
>   Java program that will allow you to
>   view the structure of a JDBC compliant
>   database, browse the data in tables,
>   issue SQL commands etc, see
>   [Introduction](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots). The minimum version of
>   Java supported is 1.6.x as of SQuirreL
>   version 3.0. See the [Old Versions](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=old) page
>   for versions of SQuirreL that will
>   work with older versions of Java.
>
> SQuirreL's functionality can be
>   extended through the use of [plugins](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins).
>
> A short introduction can be found
>   [here](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots). To see the change history
>   (including changes not yet released)
>   click [here](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=changes).
>
> For a more detailed introduction see
>   the [English](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/paper/SQuirreL_us.pdf) or [German](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/paper/SQuirreL_de.pdf) of our paper on
>   SQuirreL.
>
> Susan Cline graciously took the time
>   to document the [steps](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/SQuirreL_Derby.html) she followed to
>   setup an Apache Derby database from
>   scratch and use the SQuirreL SQL
>   Client to explore it.
>
> Quite some time ago Kulvir Singh
>   Bhogal wrote a great [tutorial](http://www-106.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/dm-0312bhogal/index.html) on
>   SQuirreL and published it at the IBM
>   developerWorks site. He has kindly
>   allowed us to mirror it [locally](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/kulvir/tutorial.html). The
>   tutorial is not really up to date but
>   especially for doing the first steps
>   it is still of help.
>
> SQuirrel was originally released under
>   the GNU General Public License. Since
>   version 1.1beta2 it has been released
>   under the GNU Lesser General Public
>   License.

It's maybe not the most nice looking application but it does its job, and pretty fast: add or configure your driver, create an alias, and there you go. Actually, it's my favorite Universal SQL Client.

Comment: Am I in the minority that thinks SQL Squirrel is just plain awful?  It runs like maple syrup on my 8 core, 16GB SSD machine, takes forever to open, hangs all the time and the maximize button goes full screen?? Really?  If only HeidiSQL could connect to DB2 then I would be much happier.

Answer (score 9):

I'd agree with Pascal about [SQuirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), that does the job for almost everything.

However if I remember rightly, its support for SQL triggers is lacking - it couldn't display the source code of the trigger, at least in the version I was using (3.0.2)

For this scenario, I found the free (but not open-source) [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) does the job, which in itself is a more than decent tool.

If I'm not working with triggers though, I'd recommend using SQuirrel SQL

Comment: Giving an upvote for SQL Workbench, it's the best SQL UI I've used to date. Rock solid stable, fast and loads of attention to detail. Regarding the license, it seems to be open source for most practical interpretations of the term but does use a non standard license.

Comment: SQL Workbench/J appears to be open sourced under the Apache 2.0 License now.   The source can be downloaded from the website

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to throw in a vote for [DbVisualizer](http://dbvis.com/).

Comment: DB Visualizer isn't open source but it has a free version.

Comment: Ah, I missed the "open source" condition. Hopefully freeware is good enough though!

Comment: For anything but the most basic functionality you need the commercial version and the price on that has continued to ratchet up over and over as time wears on. I understand their need to make money and in a business environment where the pockets are deeper, it's an excellent tool. For individuals who are working open source or hobby programming, you'll probably need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

[henplus](https://github.com/neurolabs/henplus) is worth trying out - it's a command-line JDBC client. I've used it to create production apps.